# MDCSnackbarManager buttonFont not working

Tags: ios, swift, material-components, material-components-ios

I am currently using [Material IO Components](https://material.io/design/components/snackbars.html) to create a snackbar needed for the app I'm working on, and it's got everything I need except for one little thing: I need to be able to change the font of the action button, but using the attributes provided in the documentation doesn't work.

In the [MDCSnackbarManager](https://material.io/develop/ios/components/snackbars/api-docs/Classes/MDCSnackbarManager.html) there is a `buttonFont` attribute, but that doesn't work (the `messageFont` works just fine though)

There is also a `buttonFont` attribute inside the [MDCSnackbarMessageView](https://material.io/develop/ios/components/snackbars/api-docs/Classes/MDCSnackbarMessageView.html) but that doesn't work either.

The code that I've tried so far are these (with the messageFont being the only working one among the three)

```
MDCSnackbarManager.messageFont = UIFont(name: "Lato-Bold", size: 18)
MDCSnackbarManager.buttonFont = UIFont(name: "Lato-Bold", size: 13)
MDCSnackbarMessageView.appearance().buttonFont = UIFont(name: "Lato-Bold", size: 13)
```

Any suggestions or solutions on how to fix this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Yes, sorry for the late response. After coming back to the office it seems that the problem fixed itself already and that rebuilding the project may have fixed it. I did just install the new fonts being used to maybe it had something to do with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried and `buttonFont` works normally with below code

```
MDCSnackbarManager.buttonFont = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 30)
```

[image]